# Translation of a dense set in a normed vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I would like to prove that if $X$ is, let's say, a normed vector space, and $A$ is a dense subset of $X$, and $x_0 \in X$, that $\{x_0\} + A$ is also dense in $X$.

I know that translation by a point is a homeomorphism, but not translation by a set. I have also tried using sequences, and using closure arguments. Is there any easy way to do this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set is dense if it meets every non-empty open set. $V$ meets $x_0+A$ iff $V-x_0$ meets $A$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

An elementary proof, using sequences, is the following:

Let $x\in X$.

$A$ is dense and therefore there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ such that $ x_n\to x-x_0$. So the sequence $y_n=x_0 + x_n$ is in $\left \{ x_0 \right \}+A$ and $y_n\to x_0+x-x_0=x$. So $x\in\overline{ \left \{ x_0 \right \}+A}$ and therefore $\left \{ x_0 \right \}+A$ is dense.